# ConEmu setup tabs - path is always wrong

Tags: console

Could someone please help me to setup ConEmu tabs. Did so far:
Added several tabs but all of them are having same path

My settings are:

[image: screenshot]
What am I doing wrong (It is PC Windows 10)

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#example-3

Comment: @mtak It does not allow me to save when editing path. That is the issue

Comment: @Zoran I have no idea how to fix it. All I did was insert the picture into your post.